# Reusable code in PSL(VHDL)

Tags: hardware, vhdl, verification, assertions

Currently I'm writing assertions using PSL (RTL is in VHDL). Totally 30 + IPs are there I want to reuse the same psl file for all the modules

```
vunit IP1_assert ip1_top() {

signal reg_1 :std_uloic_vector(15 downto 0);

reg_1 : <= signal ip_1.inst_1.inst_2.clk_reg : std_ulogic_vector(15 downto 0)>>;

}

vunit IP2_assert ip2_top() {

signal reg_1 :std_uloic_vector(15 downto 0);

reg_1 : <= signal ip_2.inst_1.inst_2.clk_reg : std_ulogic_vector(15 downto 0)>>;

}
```

How to change the above one as reusable one (i.e 2 Vunits into one).

In other words any ideas:

1. to replace the pathnames  ip_1 and ip_2 as generic one,
2. can we pass entity name as a parmeter to PSL Vunit?

Comment: the tags are unclear... why "hardware"? and not "psl"...

Answer (score 0):

A vunit extends an architecture. For example your vunit IP1_assert extends the (not named) architecture of your entity ip1_top(). You can be even more specific and extend only a specific arcitecture by using ip1_top(). So you cannot use the same PSL file for all your modules. But you could create a new module (with entity and architecure) which contains your PSL code and instantiate and connect this module in all your PSL files. So you would have individual PSL-files for each of your modules, but you would have only 1 module which contains the PSL code. You also could try to put your PSL into a function which you define in a package and then "use" this package from each of your PSL files, but I never tried this.

Comment: Upps, I did not pay attention, this question is really old ...